# Some apps do not display on iPod

Tags: applications, ipod-touch

I have installed 150 apps on my iPod Touch, but I have found that some apps do not display. Is there any limitation on the number of apps that can be displayed?

Comment: hi user606, I removed the your greeting because the first line of the question is displayed in the summary on the home page. I've also rephrased it slightly to hopefully clarify the meaning.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have iOS 4.0 or don't use folders, or if you are using an older version and do not have the jailbreak app Categories, the maximum amount of pages of apps it will display is 9 pages. 9 * 16 = 144 apps. You can still find the other apps in the search option, on the leftmost page, if you use iPhone OS 3.0 or newer.